# Like system in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to implement a like system in Django, but I'm getting FOREIGN KEY constraint failed error

models.py

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="likes")
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="likes")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username} {self.article.Title}"

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created_at',)
```

views.py

```
def like(request, slug, pk):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        try:
            like = Like.objects.get(article__slug=slug, user_id=request.user.id)
            like.delete()
        except:
            Like.objects.create(article_id=pk, user_id=request.user.id)
        return redirect('blog:article_detail', slug)
```

urls.py

```
path('like/<slug:slug>/<int:pk>', views.like, name='like_article')
```

Comment: What is the `pk` here? The primary key of the article? Or of the user?

Comment: Please post the error as a code fragment, not an image.

Comment: pk is primary key of the article

Comment: can you share the part of the template where you create the path to that view?

Comment: I haven't set up the template for this yet

Comment: then how are you triggering the view logic?

Comment: I am currently testing it with url

Comment: then likely the article has not `1` as primary key...

Comment: Can you post the error? Preferably error stack trace as a code.

Comment: this is error:

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Comment: @Art bro I tried this before but it didn't work !!
and got this error
`Like() got an unexpected keyword argument 'article__id'`

Comment: @Art: you can not use double underscores here, since you *create* an object, you do not filter, so all values should be part of *direct* fields.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Exactly!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, sorry, my bad. Mahdi, Maybe you need to check if the article with the given value exists before adding it. Also, I don't you can have the same related names for both user and article.